# Wo und wie werden "Nachcousin" und "Nachcousine" verwendet?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, regional

Ich komme aus dem Raum Pfalz/Nord-Baden und kenne die Wörter **Nachcousin** und **Nachcousine** (jeweils mit langem 'a'). In meinem Sprachgebrauch bezeichnet dies Verwandte etwa gleichen Alters (/der gleichen Generation), mit denen ich (genau) ein Urgroßelternpaar gemein habe:

- Teile ich die Eltern mit einer Person, heißt sie *Bruder/Schwester*.
- Teile ich ein Großelternpaar mit einer Person, heißt sie *Cousin/Cousine*.
- Teile ich ein Urgroßelternpaar, heißt sie *Nachcousin/Nachcousine*.

Dabei ist das Präfix **Nach-** auch stapelbar; d. h., wenn ich ein Ururgroßelternpaar mit einer Person teilen würde, wäre sie meine **Nachnachcousine** bzw. mein **Nachnachcousin**.

Nun hat eine oberflächliche Recherche im Netz ergeben, dass die Begriffe nicht sehr verbreitet zu sein scheinen und dass der Gebrauch auch schwankt zwischen der von mir beschriebenen Bedeutung und "Kind meines Cousins/meiner Cousine" oder "Cousin/Cousine meiner Mutter/meines Vaters".

**Meine Frage:**
Wo im deutschsprachigen Raum sind diese Begriffe bekannt und in welcher Bedeutung werden sie dort verwendet?

Comment: Noch nie gehört. Ich glaube, andernorts sagt man "Großcousin(e)".

Comment: Es wäre nett, wenn alle, die kommentieren und die Sache nie gehört haben, dazuschreiben könnten, woher sie kommen. Den "Standort" dabei zu haben, könnte hilfreich sein. (Okay, @Matthias, du kommst laut deinem Profil aus München :-))

Comment: Ostösterreich, noch nie gehört. Großcousin(e) gibt es natürlich.

Comment: Ich wäre neben Großcousine spontan noch auf "Cousine zweiten Grades" gekommen. Keine Ahnung, ob das überhaupt stimmt. Raum Köln kennt keine "Nachcousinen".

Comment: Interessant zu sehen, dass das Wort [Großcousin(e)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verwandtschaftsbeziehung#Gro.C3.9F-) so ziemlich denselben diffusen Bedeutungsumfang hat, wie "Nachcousin(e)".

Comment: In (Ober-)Schwaben hab ich auch noch nie was von "Nachcousinen" gehört. Hier ist Großcousin geläufig.

Comment: Hessen, ebenfalls noch nie gehört, kenne ebenfalls Großcousin(e).

Comment: @Chris Da hast Du gleich zweimal recht. Neben meinem jetzigen städtisch-bayerischen Umfeld kann ich das auch für meine sächsische Familie bezeugen.

Comment: Ich halte es für keine gute Idee hier 50 Antworten zu sammeln mit offenem Ende, für jede Region die den Begriff kennt oder nicht. Wenn, dann müsste man das Community-Wiki mit einer Liste "hier so verwendet" und einer "hier unbekannt".

Comment: @userunknown: Ich habe eine Antwort als Community-Wiki erstellt. Leider hab' ich keine Ahnung, wie man das für die Frage und für alle weiteren Antworten auch einstellt.

Comment: @Chris Ich glaub die Idee war, genau zwei Antworten zu erzeugen und eine Antwort besagt "Verwendet" und die zweite "nicht verwendet". – Deine Frage kann durch einen Mod CW gemacht werden.

Comment: Es folgt i.d.R. einfach der Logik des Begriffs Großtante.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Negativ - Nachcousin wird nicht verwendet:

*(bitte alphabetisch einordnen)*

Stattdessen ist Großcousin üblich:

- Bayern
- Berlin
- Franken (Unter- und Mittel-)
- Hessen
- Mitteldeutschland (Sachsen, Sachsen-Anhalt, Thüringen)
- Moselfranken
- Nordrhein-Westfalen
- Oberschwaben
- Österreich

Stattdessen ist *Cousin zweiten Grades* üblich, da Großcousin eine andere als die o. g. Bedeutung hat:

- Niedersachsen, Süd- -- Großcousin bedeutet Cousin des Vaters oder der Mutter.

Comment: Schweiz: Cucusin(e) - kann das jemand bestätigen?

Comment: Ich kenne aus Sachsen-Anhalt Kusskusine/ Couscousin(e) und nicht, wie in der Antwort behauptet  den/die Groußcouin(e). Die richtige Schreibweise ist unklar & dazu konnte ich bisher auch in Wörterbüchern nichts finden. Allerdings gibt es einige Einträge dazu in anderen Hilfe-Foren, z.B. http://www.helpster.de/kusscousine-so-klaeren-sie-die-verwandtschaftsverhaeltnisse_84282 @Ralph M. Rickenbach: Das ähnelt Deinem Begriff Cucusin(e) und hat vllt. einen ähnlichen Ursprung.

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Wenn ich es richtig bedenke, dann ist die Schreibweise Cou(s)cousin(e) wahrscheinlicher, da französichen Ursprungs. Danke.

Comment: Komisch, hier sehe ich Großcousin für Österreich, dabei kenne ich hier, wenn man das schon genau sagen will, nur _Cousin zweiten Grades_, während Großcousin der Cousin meines Vaters/meiner Mutter ist. (Die Situation ist für mich also genau wie hier nur für Niedersachsen angegeben.)

Answer (score 4):

### Positiv - Nachcousin wird verwendet:

- Südpfalz

Ich bin in der [Südpfalz](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%BCdpfalz) geboren und mir ist der Ausdruck *Nachcousin(e)* bekannt im Sinne von "Cousin(e) zweiten Grades", also eine Person, mit der ich ein Urgroßelternpaar gemeinsam habe.

Der Begriff beschränkt sich nicht nur auf mein näheres Umfeld, sondern scheint hier allgemein bekannt zu sein. Kurt Beck verwendete ihn in einem [Interview für FAZ.net](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/inland/im-gespraech-kurt-beck-gott-haettst-de-doch-des-maul-gehalten-12132917.html):

> *FAZ:* **In die Christliche Arbeiterjugend sind Sie später, mit 13, trotzdem gegangen.**
>   *Beck:* Das war eher Zufall: Mein **Nachcousin** hatte die Gruppe gegründet, und dann habe ich da auch mitgemacht.

Kurt Beck stammt aus der Nähe von Bad Bergzabern, einer Stadt in der Südpfalz. Mit welcher Bedeutung er den Begriff *Nachcousin* hier verwendet, kann ich natürlich nicht sagen.

Answer (score 1):

Nachcousine wird auch im deutschsprachigen Südtirol gebraucht, jedenfalls gemäss meiner (sic!) Nachcousine Helga aus Brixen – sie ist eine Cousine meiner Mutter und sagte mir kürzlich, sie sei (eben) meine Nachcousine.

Answer (score 0):

Ich stamme ebenfalls aus der Südpfalz aus Rheinzabern und Nachcousin oder Nachcousine sind hier geläufige Verwandtschaftsbegriffe und ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, dass die Südpfalz bei den Verwandtschaftsbegriffen ein Alleinstellungsmerkmal hat.

Nachcousins und Nachcousinen bezeichnen den Verwandtschaftsgrad der Kinder von Cousins und Cousinen zueinander selbst.

Großcousin und Großcousine hingegen sind die Bezeichnungen für den Familienstand/Benennung der Kinder von Cousinen und Cousins der Eltern zu diesen Elterncousins.
Der Großcousin, die Großcousine ist also die Verwandtschaftsbezeichnung für die Elterncousins oder Elterncousins.

Zusammenfassend:
Wir Kinder von Cousins und Cousinen unserer Eltern sind Nachcousins/Nachcousinen.

Die Cousins/Cousinen unserer Eltern sind unsere Großcousins/Großcousinen. Gar nicht verwirrend, wenn man es weiß.

Comment: Aber sehr verwirrend, wenn man's anders kennt. ;)